# Is there a way to use a random link twice? i.e. like the Wikipedia Random Article Generator but for a different site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pip

I'm extremely new to programming and I wanted to code something for my first project that I actually considered useful, so I drew inspiration from the typical project "Random Wikipedia Article Generator" in order to create one with the exact same functionality (fetch the name of a random article, ask if the user wants to read it, if they say yes then open it up, otherwise fetch a new one and so on) but using Stanford's Encyclopedia of Philosophy (taking advantage of the fact that they have a similar Random Entry function) and it was going well until I ran it after having to make some adjustments to it because of initial problems with the *.text* function.

It would initially display a certain title but when selecting the option to go ahead it takes me to a different page than selected. I've tried several things to get it to reuse the same url that prompts the title but I haven't been able to do so. If someone could help me fetch the correct link for the second part or correct my code in some way in order to make it functional I would very much appreciate it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

while True:
    url = "https://plato.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/encyclopedia/random"
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
    for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    print(title.get_text() + "\nDo you want to view this entry?" + "\nType Y for Yes or N for No")
    ans = input("").lower()
    if (ans == "y"):
        url2 = url
        webbrowser.open(url)
        break
    elif (ans == "n"):
        print("Ok. \nTry again!")
        continue
    else:
        print("Invalid choice!!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reqs.url` to view the redirected URL. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:
    url = "https://plato.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/encyclopedia/random"
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
    for title in soup.find_all("title"):
        ans = input(
            title.get_text()
            + "\nDo you want to view this entry?"
            + "\nType Y for Yes or N for No: "
        ).lower()
        if ans == "y":
            print("The link is: {}".format(reqs.url))
            break
        elif ans == "n":
            print("Ok. \nTry again!")
            continue
        else:
            print("Invalid choice!!")
            break
```

Prints:

```
Arabic and Islamic Natural Philosophy and Natural Science (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)

Do you want to view this entry?
Type Y for Yes or N for No: y
The link is: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/arabic-islamic-natural/
```

Comment: It worked great, I was hoping to have the website automatically open up but at this point I'll take anything. Thank you so much!